# Combining two tables in a complex way

Tags: mysql, sql

**The situation:**

I have the main table, lets call it `MainTable`.

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+ 
|  Id (PK)| Title    | Text     | Type     |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+ 
|   1     | Some Text|More Stuff| A        | 
|   2     | Another  | Example  | B        | 
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

And I have a second table called `TranslationsTable`, in which the Id field is the representation of the `MainTable` row Id (no foreign key, as it can be refering to different tables), The ObjType is the ObjectType (same name as table), the FieldName is the name of the field from the ObjecType and the value has the translation value for the FieldName value in the ObjType table.

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
|   Id    | ObjType   | FieldName | Value      | Language |
+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
|   1     | MainTable | Title     | Algum Texto| PT       |
|   1     | MainTable | Text      | Mais Coisas| PT       |
+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

And because I need to search in translated fields, I figured I could use a `TEMPORARY TABLE` to do so, but then came the problem of "Which SELECT query should I use?". I read some posts about pivot table queries, but **I don't really know** how can I build a query so my temp table is something like

```
+---------+------------+------------+----------+ 
|  Id (PK)| Field_1    | Field_2    | Field_3  |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+ 
|   1     | Algum Texto| Mais Coisas| A        |  
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

I accepted AD7six answer because for 500.000 entries in the MainTable and 1.500.000 in the Translations it is roughly 30x times faster than the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That's not complex

It's just a query with one join per translated field.

That means you query/sort/whatever it like any other e.g. (Using some real names so that it's easier to read):

```
SELECT
    products.id,
    COALESCE(product_name.value, products.name) as name,
    COALESCE(product_description.value, products.description) as description
FROM
    products
LEFT JOIN
    TranslationsTable AS product_name
    ON (
        product_name.Language = 'PT' AND
        product_name.ObjectType = 'products' AND
        product_name.FieldName = 'name' AND
        product_name.id = products.id
    )
LEFT JOIN
    TranslationsTable AS product_description
    ON (
        product_description.Language = 'PT' AND
        product_description.ObjectType = 'products' AND
        product_description.FieldName = 'description' AND
        product_description.id = products.id
    )
WHERE
    product_name.value = "Algum Texto" // Find all products named "Algum Texto"
```

### You don't need a temp table

But if you want to create one, it's easy to do using the query itself:

```
CREATE TABLE
    products_pt
AS
SELECT
    products.id,
    COALESCE(product_name.value, products.name) as name,
    COALESCE(product_description.value, products.description) as description
...
```

This will create a table (no indexes) matching the structure of the query. If your data does not change frequently it can make querying your multilingual data a lot easier to manage, but has some disadvantages such as (obviously) your translation-specific table will not be up to date if the source table data changes.

Comment: It does have a Primary Key. Its Id - ObjType - FieldName (in their respective names in Portuguese)

Comment: missed the language, but it's Id - ObjType - FieldName - Language

Comment: Although your Code works like a charm, I noticed it's slightly slower than the option from Anon. I'm going to test out which one performs better in bigger tables (my translation table has a tendency to have a lot of rows). Too bad I can't choose both answers, I'll have to accept the one that is better for my case. At least both of you will get an upvote :)

Comment: If you can remove the use of COALESCE, that may make it faster. Don't forget to use explain on your queries to check for optimizations; if it's a tmp table query, there's definitely room for improvement.

Comment: As it turns out I may be wrong on that. phpMyAdmin was reporting a 0.0005 secs on Anon's code, and 0.0010 on your approach. But I was using a temp table in Anon's code and not in yours. When I used only the SELECT and no tem table it reported 0.0072 on Anon's way. Which is considerable slower. I'll have to investigate further and may accept your answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  orig.Id,
  COALESCE(xlate.Field_1, orig.Field_1) AS Field_1,
  COALESCE(xlate.Field_2, orig.Field_2) AS Field_2,
  COALESCE(xlate.Field_3, orig.Field_3) AS Field_3
FROM MainTable orig
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    Id,Field_1,Field_2,Field_3
  FROM TranslationsTable
  PIVOT(MIN(Value) FOR FieldName IN (Field_1,Field_2,Field_3)) p
  WHERE ObjType = 'MainTable'
) xlate ON (orig.Id = xlate.Id)
```

If you want to include the (untranslated) rows from MainTable that have no matches in TranslationsTable, change the INNER JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN

Another alternative is to perform the pivot manually:

```
SELECT
  orig.Id,
  COALESCE(xlate.Field_1, orig.Field_1) AS Field_1,
  COALESCE(xlate.Field_2, orig.Field_2) AS Field_2,
  COALESCE(xlate.Field_3, orig.Field_3) AS Field_3
FROM MainTable orig
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    Id,
    MIN(CASE FieldName WHEN 'Field_1' THEN Value END) AS Field_1,
    MIN(CASE FieldName WHEN 'Field_2' THEN Value END) AS Field_2,
    MIN(CASE FieldName WHEN 'Field_3' THEN Value END) AS Field_3
  FROM TranslationsTable 
  WHERE ObjType = 'MainTable'
  GROUP BY Id
) xlate ON (orig.Id = xlate.Id)
```

With a change in the MainTable schema like others have suggested, you won't need the repetition for (Field_1,Field_2,Field_3).  It makes the code easier to maintain and modify.

Comment: Thank you for your (very quick) answer. I'll try it out right away and let you know.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error at line 10. Is there a PIVOT in MySQL?

Comment: I accomplished it with MAX(IF(i.FieldName = 'Field_1', i.Value, NULL)) as Field_1  Would it be better your way?

Comment: Actually the Fields name should be dynamic, but that I can manage even if doing so in PHP.

Comment: My *"CASE FieldName WHEN 'Field_1' THEN Value END"* is logically equivalent to your *"IF(FieldName = 'Field_1', Value, NULL)"*, so no difference there.

Comment: MIN() vs MAX() will only matter if the TranslationTable contains more than one entry for a specific field/obj/lang combination.  Since that would definitely be a bug, you can prevent it from occurring by adding a composite primary key on the TranslationTable like AD7six recommends.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I accepted your answer because (from what I found out) its quicker than the "Left Joins" aproach (the number of translated fields is variable and could be up to 4 or 5 fields, and the joins become slower)